# Insert after event trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I need to create a trigger in SQL Server for filling a table if an event is done.

My code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_EsportaMancatiContatti]
ON  [dbo].[Lav_CollaudiVodaf_StoricoMancatiContatti]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IDPRATStorico INT;
    DECLARE @IDPRAT INT;
    DECLARE @CodRichiestaCRM INT;
    DECLARE @IDESITO INT;
    DECLARE @Telefono VARCHAR;
    DECLARE @DataOraContatto INT;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @IDPRATStorico = (SELECT IDPRATStorico FROM inserted);
    SET @IDPRAT = (SELECT IDPRAT FROM inserted);
    SET @CodRichiestaCRM = (SELECT CodRichiestaCRM FROM inserted);
    SET @IDESITO = (SELECT IDESITO FROM inserted);
    SET @Telefono = (SELECT Telefono  FROM inserted);
    SET @DataOraContatto = (SELECT DataOraContatto FROM inserted);

    IF @IDESITO = 18 AND count(@IDPRAT) < 3
    BEGIN
        INSERT Lav_CollaudiVodaf_StoricoMancatiContatti

        SET IDPRATStorico=@IDPRATStorico
        SET CodRichiestaCRM=@CodRichiestaCRM
        SET IDESITO=@IDESITO
        SET Telefono=Telefono
        SET DataOraContatto=@DataOraContatto

        WHERE IdPrat=@IDPRAT;
    END

END;
```

It throws some error.

Target: I have a table filled with contacts, I need to insert these record into another table, if the IDESITO is 18 and the count in the new table is < 3.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: First, `inserted` is a table with possibly many rows. The trigger should  process table, not single values.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT Telefono  FROM inserted` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 0):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_EsportaMancatiContatti]
ON  [dbo].[Lav_CollaudiVodaf_StoricoMancatiContatti]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        INSERT INTO Lav_CollaudiVodaf_StoricoMancatiContatti(
                  IDPRATStorico,
                  CodRichiestaCRM,
                  IDESITO,
                  Telefono,
                  DataOraContatto
         )
        SELECT TOP 3
                IDPRATStorico,
                CodRichiestaCRM,
                IDESITO,
                Telefono,
                DataOraContatto
        FROM INSERTED
        WHERE IDESITO = 18
 END;
```

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with count(@IDPRAT) < 3. I guess you might want only the top 3 rows